# EasyAdminBundle - Key "nullable" not found - Error on creating or editing items

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I just want to use the [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) for my backend. But after installation via composer I got the following error if I click a edit oder create button:

If I click the "Create" button (or any "Edit" button) in the backend, I get the following error message:

> Key "nullable" for array with keys "css_class, format, help, label, type, fieldType, dataType, virtual, sortable, template, type_options, fieldName, columnName, property" does not exist in @EasyAdmin/form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig at line 39

I changed nothing on my entities. The EasyAdminConfiguration is this:

```
easy_admin:
    site_name: 'backend'
    design:
        form_theme: 'vertical'
    entities:
        Blogpost:
            class:      NI\BlogBundle\Entity\Post
            label:      Artikel
        BlogKategorie:
            class:      NI\BlogBundle\Entity\PostCategory
            label:      Kategorien
        Benutzer:
            class:      NI\UserBundle\Entity\User
            label:      Benutzerkonten
        Unternehmen:
            class:      NI\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company
            label:      Unternehmen
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There was no default value vor "nullable" defined (see bugfix on github: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/commit/0fac932646280e4ede02f97430aab503108897fb).

**Resources/views/form/bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig**

```
     <div class="{{ block('form_group_class') }}">
         {{ form_widget(form) }}

     <div class="{{ block('form_group_class') }}">
         {{ form_widget(form) }}

-            {% if _field_type in ['datetime', 'datetimetz', 'date', 'time'] and easyadmin.field.nullable %}
+            {% if _field_type in ['datetime', 'datetimetz', 'date', 'time'] and easyadmin.field.nullable|default(false) %}
             <div class="nullable-control">
                 <label>
                     <input type="checkbox" {% if data is null %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
```

**Resources/views/form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig**

```
      {{- form_label(form, _field_label|trans(_trans_parameters)) -}}
     {{- form_widget(form) -}}

-        {% if _field_type in ['datetime', 'datetimetz', 'date', 'time'] and easyadmin.field.nullable %}
+        {% if _field_type in ['datetime', 'datetimetz', 'date', 'time'] and easyadmin.field.nullable|default(false) %}
         <div class="nullable-control">
             <label>
                 <input type="checkbox" {% if data is null %}checked="checked"{% endif %}>
```